# Renovate config path

Tags: node.js, docker, aws-lambda, renovate

I need to dynamically write the config for the renovate bot.  As it's being run in AWS Lambda Docker, the filesystem is locked, bar `/tmp/` so I need to wrote it there.

How do I give renovate a path to a custom config file?

An alternative would be for me to bundle several configs, but I'd still need to be able to tell renovate which one to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RENOVATE_CONFIG_FILE` in environment variables, e.g. `RENOVATE_CONFIG_FILE=/tmp/renovate-config.js`. See https://docs.renovatebot.com/getting-started/running/#global-config for more details